# Pivot in BIG QUERY giving error for row data having a space . Fields must contain only letters numbers underscores start with a letter or underscore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to do PIVOTING in Big query by using below query

```
select * from
(SELECT desc,qty,RSN_DESC FROM `TABLE`)
  PIVOT(SUM(qty) FOR RSN_DESC IN ('Example1', 'Example2', 'Example3', 'Example 3','Example4','Example 5',''))
```

If you look closely the "Example 3" and "Example 5" we have a space in between data, like "Store Ops" (an actual example from my data). Pivot does not work for such data and it gives error as

```
Invalid field name "Store Ops". Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 300 characters long.
```

Any suggestions on how can I handle this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below instead

```
select * from
(SELECT `desc`,qty,RSN_DESC FROM `TABLE`)
PIVOT(SUM(qty) FOR replace(RSN_DESC, ' ', '_') IN ('Example1', 'Example2', 'Example3', 'Example_3','Example4','Example_5',''))
```

in this case 'Example3', 'Example_3' will be different columns

or

```
select * from
(SELECT `desc`,qty,RSN_DESC FROM `TABLE`)
PIVOT(SUM(qty) FOR replace(RSN_DESC, ' ', '') IN ('Example1', 'Example2', 'Example3', 'Example4','Example5',''))
```

in this case 'Example3' and 'Example 3' will be collapsed into one column