# I have issue with code related to pivot in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, syntax-error

```
Select category,heart,scared,peeking,hate,interested, adore,dislike,want,love,disgust,like ,super love,indifferent,cherish,worried,intrigued
from
(SELECT category,reactedType 
from `myproject02-337920.socialMedia.Analysis_reaction` 
 ) as source
pivot
(
  count(reactedType) for reactedType in ('heart','scared','peeking','hate','interested', 'adore','dislike','want','love','disgust','like' ,'super love','indifferent','cherish','worried','intrigued')
)
```

Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword LIKE at [1:87]
have problem with like and super love in select statement

Comment: Like is a reserved word, try `[like]`

Comment: I gave pivot  name pi , Now pi.like is working but ' super love' in select statement is not working. Thanks for your reply

Comment: same again, needs `[]` cause of the space

Comment: [ ] is not working in big query. I tried it  : Expected "," or "]" but got identifier "love" at [1:103]

Comment: Column name can't have a space. and to escape a reserved keyword, you should use a backtick(`) instead of brackets([]).
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#column_names.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668692/pivot-in-big-query-giving-error-for-row-data-having-a-space-fields-must-contai  would be helpful when your pivot column values are not appropriate for column names.

Comment: thanks, it worked after using replace function.  This is my first time asking a question in stack overflow. Quick reply thanks Jaytiger and Nathan_Sav